# Set of elements that do not generate $G$ with another one.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

Consider a finite $2$-generated group $G$, not cyclic. Fix $a\in G$. Let's denote by $J_a$ the set of elements of $G$ that do not generate $G$ together with $a$, i.e.
$$J_a=\{g\in G: \langle g,a \rangle \neq G\}.$$
Now, is it true that $J_a$ is a subgroup?

- $1_G\in J_a$,
- If $g\in J_a$, then $g^{-1}\in J_a$,
- If $g,h\in J_a$, assume that $\langle gh, a\rangle=G$, then $a$ and $gh$ are respectively in two maximal subgroups of $G$, call them $H$ and $K$, such that $\{gh,a\}\notin H\cap K$. So, from this point I can not argue to obtain that $gh\in J_a$...

Well, if $J_a$ is a subgroup, who is this object, for every $a\in G$? Of course, the union of maximal subgroups containing $a$ is in $J_a$.

For example, take the group $A_5$ and fix $a=(12345)\in A_5$. By calculations, I have found that $J_{(12345)}=N_G(\langle a \rangle)$, which is maximal in $A_5$. How can explain this fact?

Comment: The union of maximal subgroups containing $a$ **is** $J_a$: if $g\in J_a$, then $\langle g,a\rangle$ is itself contained in a maximal subgroup containing $a$, hence $g$ lies in a maximal subgroup containing $a$. And if $M$ is a maximal subgroup containing $a$, and $g\in M$, then $\langle g,a\rangle\subseteq M\neq G$, so $g\in J_a$.

Comment: $A_5$ has exactly six maximal subgroups of order divisible by $5$, all of them of order $10$; each of them contains four $5$-cycles. That accounts for all twenty four $5$-cycles in $A_5$, so for each $5$-cycle there is one and only one maximal subgroup that contains it. Hence your $J_a$ is the unique maximal subgroup of $A_5$ containing $(12345)$, which happens to be its normalizer (since a subgroup of order $5$ is always normal in a subgroup of order $10$).

Answer (score 3):

As I noted above, $J_a$ is exactly the union of the maximal subgroups containing $a$. In your example, because for each $5$-cycle $\sigma$ there is a unique maximal subgroup of $A_5$ that contains $\sigma$, namely its normalizer, your calculation follows.

However, in general $J_a$ is not a subgroup. Consider $G=S_5$, which is $2$-generated (e.g., by $(12)$ and $(12345)$). Let $a=(12)$. Then $J_a$ contains the one point stabilizers of $3$, $4$, and $5$ (so, any permutation that fixes at least one point from $\{3,4,5\}$; in particular, it contains all transpositions), but $J_a\neq G$. Hence, $S_5=\langle J_a\rangle\neq J_a$, so $J_a$ is not a subgroup.